# SH linux: Syntax error: word unexpected

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, sh

I want know what am I doing wrong in this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=neocloud
PATH_TO_JAR=/etc/neocloud/cloud.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/neocloud-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

executing via `sh` I get the following error message:

> Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")

But in the `case` command I've the `in` word.

Anyone know how to fix this bug?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what's the value of `$1` ?

Comment: $1 is the first commandline argument

Comment: I know what this is, I'd like to know the *value* of `$1`.

Comment: start | stop | restart

Comment: Does this gives the error if you reduce to [this](https://gist.github.com/ThomasAy/2e6b599009002fcfc9713524256264f2) ?

Comment: By any chance, did you give it a value that has 2 words? e.g. `./my-service "start now"` or `./my-service start\ now`? That is thie only case I can think of, which can cause this issue. If that is the case, always quote variables, as `case "$1" in`

Comment: No. I use just one word. And i used quotes to try to solve, but the same error happened.

Comment: In the future, btw, try to conform with the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- code samples should be **minimal**, containing the smallest amount of code that will reproduce the same problem, and **verifiable** -- meaning you should copy-and-paste it back out of your question, try to run it, and make sure this still causes the bug (which will catch things like hidden characters).

Comment: ...also, ideally, bugs found by http://shellcheck.net/ should be fixed before a question is asked here.

Comment: If in doubt, add the `-v` switch to see exactly where your script ends up, e.g. `#!/bin/sh -v` in the first line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**As posted here, your code is syntactically valid POSIX-like shell code**, which you can verify at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) (which will, however, warn you about potentially unwanted side effects due to not double-quoting your variable references (e.g., `echo $PID_PATH_NAME` rather than `echo "$PID_PATH_NAME"`), which however does NOT apply to `$1` in the `case` statement<sup>[1]</sup>
).

Similarly, copying the code in your question and pasting it into a new file and using `sh` on Ubuntu (which is Dash) to execute it, works fine too.

**Thus - unless your `sh` is not what it should be - I suspect that you have "weird" characters in your shell file**, such as Unicode whitespace outside the standard ASCII range, which may *look* like normal whitespace, but isn't; the Unicode no-break space character (`U_00A0`, UTF8-encoded as `0xC2 0xA0`) is an example.

To look for such characters, run the following (where `script` represents your script):

```
LC_ALL=C cat -e script
```

and look for `M-` and `^<letter>` sequences in the output; for instance, the aforementioned no-break space shows up as `M-BM-`.

---

[1] **Double-quoting the argument given to the `case` statement doesn't hurt, but *is not necessary***.

While unquoted parameter/variable references are word-split and pathname-expanded in *most* places in POSIX-like shells, `case` is a curious exception.

The following demonstrates this, and works with all major POSIX-like shells (`dash`, `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`):

```
$ sh -c 'case $1 in "foo *") echo "match";; *) echo "nomatch"; esac' - 'foo *'
match
```

Literal argument `foo *` matches the `case` branch, even though `$1` is *unquoted*.
(Contrast this with the typical situation (e.g., `echo $1`), where the value of `$1` would be subject to both word-splitting and pathname expansion (globbing).)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [quoting the argument](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting)?

```
case "$1" in
...
```

Comment: This is not called casting to string. This is called quoting. Though, this CAN actualy serve as converting to string, for integer variables. But the case statement will anyway interpret it as string. Anyway, likely this could be the issue in the script. See my comment for explanation.

Comment: Quoting isn't necessary in that position in a `case` statement -- not prone to string-splitting or glob expansion.